# Java Application this operation is permitted on the event thread only Error

Tags: java, javafx, launch

I have the class `PlayerScreen` that creates the graphics of a class and i want to run it from the class `MainGUI` but i keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PlayerScreen extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Player Screen");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
}
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainGUI {
    private static Stage stage = new Stage();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         PlayerScreen screen = new PlayerScreen();
         PlayerScreen.launch(args);
        }
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        MainGUI.stage = stage;
    }
}
```

I have tried instead of `PlayerScreen.launch(args);` with `screen.launch(args);` and `Application.launch(args);` but i keep getting the same error. There is another `launch` method that includes the class but i don't know what to put in the second variable `Application.launch(MainGUI.class, args);` `args` is not accepted

Comment: make `MainGUI extends Application` instead of `PlayerScreen`.

Comment: Just omit `PlayerScreen screen = new PlayerScreen()`, and call `Application.launch(PlayerScreen.class, args);` (which will instantiate `PlayerScreen` for you). (It's not really clear what separation you are trying to achieve by having the two different classes here.)

Comment: @James_D thanks, that worked. I need to have two classes because MainGui also has to show two other stages. (You can write it as an answer so you get the points by the way)

Comment: But in that case, `PlayerScreen` should **not** be a subclass of application. The `Application` subclass (there should only be one) is supposed to represent the entire application. Even with the fix I suggested, you still have this hugely misconfigured.

Answer (score 4):

make `MainGUI extends Application` instead of `PlayerScreen`.

in Application methods start() is called on the special thread which should be used for all UI interactions. Also, Application prepared first `Stage` for you. So you don't need to explicitly create it.

Answer (score 0):

you Should use Platform.runLater(()->{//code here})